# htaccess execution order and priority

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, htaccess

Can anyone explain to me in what order apache executes .htaccess files residing in different levels of the same path and how the rewrite rules therein are prioritized?

For example, why doesn't the rewrite rule in the first .htaccess below work and is the one in `/blog` prioritized?

.htaccess in `/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog offline.html [L]
```

.htaccess in `/blog`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

PS: I'm not simply looking for an answer but for a way to understand the apache/mod_rewrite internals ... *why* is more important to me than *how* to fix this,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Read the [Apache Tutorial: .htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html), mainly the section "How directives are applied", which states:

> The configuration directives found in
> a .htaccess file are applied to the
> directory in which the .htaccess file
> is found, and to all subdirectories
> thereof. However, it is important to
> also remember that there may have been
> .htaccess files in directories higher
> up. Directives are applied in the
> order that they are found. Therefore,
> a .htaccess file in a particular
> directory may override directives
> found in .htaccess files found higher
> up in the directory tree. And those,
> in turn, may have overridden
> directives found yet higher up, or in
> the main server configuration file
> itself.

But for the special case of mod_rewrite read "[Rules inherited from the parent scope are applied after rules specified in the child scope.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#:%7E:text=Rules%20inherited%20from%20the%20parent%20scope%20are%20applied%20after%20rules%20specified%20in%20the%20child%20scope.)"

Comment: mod_rewrite is a special case. Rewrite rules are applied bottom up. First the rules in the subdirectory then the rules in the parent directory.

Comment: The doc listed above is for Apache 2.2.  For the current version of apache, go to this link instead http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: @GetFree Is this the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#:~:text=Rules%20inherited%20from%20the%20parent%20scope%20are%20applied%20after%20rules%20specified%20in%20the%20child%20scope.) for the "sub rules then parent rules" behavior you stated?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `RewriteOptions inherit` to inherit the rewrite rules of the parent directory. However, the parent directory's rewrite rules will be applied later, as per [the documentation on RewriteOptions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions).

Comment: Rewrite directives for parent directories will be applied even *without* this statement (which is somewhat confusing) but I suppose this can be used to perform a virtual copy + paste of directives from the parent to the child (which may have different rewrite bases).  No wonder mod_rewrite messes with your head sometimes... Argh.

Comment: @SimonEast "Rewrite directives for parent directories will be applied even without this statement" - Are you sure? Do you have a reference? Specifically, `mod_rewrite` directives are _not_ inherited by default (different to other modules). You would need a `RewriteOptions InheritXXXX` directive _somewhere_ for directives to be inherited. However, this gets more complex on Apache 2.4+ with the `InheritDown` option that can be specified in _parent_ directories and the server config which then controls child directories.

Comment: Apache v2.3.10 allows you to use InheritBefore, and if you're using v2.4.8 or higher you can apply InheritDownBefore from the parent directory which forces all children below it to inherit the rules.